# NHibernate - Lock Deserialized Object

Tags: serialization, nhibernate, deserialization

i have a issue when i lock an object wich is deserialized.

e.g.:

```
var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
var item = session.QueryOver<T>().Where(x => x.Id = "1").FutureValue().Value;

var serializedObject = Serializer.Serialize(item);

//do something with the serialized object
//...

var deserializedObject = Deserializer.Deserialze(serializedObject);
//lock record
session.Lock(deserializedObject, lockMode);
```

Error:

```
a different with the same identifier value was already associated with the session...
```

But the SessionId in the error ist the same SessionId from the opened session.

If i lock the original "item" then it works.

Now is my question how can i interact with serialization/deserialization?

Thanks in advance und best regards

Comment: NHibernate is tracking exactly one instance of your T... You are trying to use another instance of T (the one returned by `Deserialize`). You have to `session.Merge` the deserialized object (and note that `session.Merge` returns another object! the one attached to the `session`).

Comment: Hi xanatos, please can you explain it. Now i try session.Merge(deserializedObject); but the error is the same :(

Comment: `deserializedObject = session.Merge(deserializedObject)`

Comment: Hi xanatos, i thank you so mutch. It works perfect for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NHibernate is tracking exactly one instance of your `T`... You are trying to use another instance of `T` (the one returned by `Deserialize`). You have to `session.Merge` the deserialized object (and note that `session.Merge` returns another object that you must then use!)

For example:

```
deserializedObject = session.Merge(deserializedObject);
```

From this point on, the `deserializedObject` is the object that NHibernate is tracking.

**Remember to assign the result of session.Merge**!

**The next line is totally useless and is a common error!**

```
session.Merge(deserializedObject);
```